# LinAlgError Singular matrix for scipy.stats.multivariate_normal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gmm

I am trying to implement the code for GMM manually following the guide at this [link](https://gist.github.com/DFoly/2bb4dbf421f8bff405b4d66699c3da00)

for another dataset with text messages.

I am getting a LinAlgError because of singular matrix when calculating
probability density function. Cannot find out where I am going wrong.

```
mu = initial_means
pi=initial_pi
sigma=initial_cov
N = X.shape[0] 
gamma = np.zeros((N,C))
const_c = np.zeros(C)

for c in range(C):
            # Posterior Distribution using Bayes Rule

    zz= mvn.pdf(X,mu[c,:],sigma[c,:])
    print(zz)
    gamma[:,c] = pi[c] * zz
        # normalize across columns to make a valid probability
    gamma_norm = np.sum(gamma, axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
    gamma /= gamma_norm
```

Comment: Your matrix does not have an inverse.  Either the values you've entered are incorrect OR you need a solver like SVD that can be robust in the face of a singular matrix.

Comment: Hi Divyasshree, what are the values of `initial_means` and `initial_cov`? It looks like you are trying to use a singular `sigma`, when it needs to be non-singular.

Comment: My initial_means is a ndarray that has rows that look like this:[4.74394705e+01 6.73623412e-01 6.12863678e-01 ... 6.81845570e-03
  5.06020993e-06 1.25836846e-02] and it looks like my sigma is not invertible.I just checked

Comment: probably pseudoinverse would solve the problem for me. scipy.linalg.pinv